# 16 raster overlay/overlap

Tags: qgis, raster, overlay, mosaic, overlapping-rasters

I need to overlay 16 black & white rasters to show their level of overlap. Ideally, as the output, I would want a new raster with a range of 0-16 (i.e. 0% overlap to 100% overlap). I tried doing this with the SAGA raster calculator (followed this advice: [Calculating percent overlap of Raster Layers using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265773/calculating-percent-overlap-of-raster-layers-using-qgis)) but it did not work. I also tried combining them in the SAGA mosaic tool, but QGIS crashed every time. Is there a different method I could try?

Comment: Maybe start trying it step by step combining two rasters, not all 16 at once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution: using `r.series` and specifying it to use the `sum` of the 16 rasters. I got an output raster that shows the level of overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Use the QGIS [Cell Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiscellstatistics) tool:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I figure out that I could do it using r.series and managed to get a perfect raster file that shows the overlap :)